# Nexus 4 cannot pass the X screen after uninstalling Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, nexus-4

I followed [official Ubuntu Touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) instructions for installing/uninstalling Ubuntu.

Installation went without any problems, but after returning back Android, the device is stuck on the "X" animation and cannot proceed.

I tried the following:

- Going into recovering mode
- Flashing the device to stock version of Android (v4.2)
- Flashing the device to previous installed Android (v4.3)

The `flash-all.sh` command is executed successfully every time, but boot gets stuck at "X" animation no matter what I do.

What can I do to fix this issue? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the situation by doing the following:

- Going into the bootloader mode and selecting "Recovery"
- Holding volume up and power button until a new screen is opened
- Do a factory reset
- Wipe out partition cache
- Do a factory reset again

Everything seems to be working properly now.

Comment: That had absolutely no effect for mine.

Comment: Sorry to hear that; hope you resolved it by now. I believe this is caused by some conflict/bug so the solution might not be the same for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for your sympathy. I ended up having to replace it. Not ideal but not the end of the world either, and Google is pretty decent to deal with.